# Excel VBA 2016 - PasteSpecial fails, but not all the time

Tags: excel, vba

I've copied and pasted macros to generate an array of random pictures from a column, but I don't understand them enough to debug them. I am getting a run-time error on the *Range(MergedAreas(i)).PasteSpecial* line, but only some of the time.

I'm creating an Excel version of a game called Codenames: Pictures. Here's the [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11LayCb84I9w-6FUeGwZ0DQvVzzj2_1v0) if you want to try it out!

```
Sub DisplayRandomPics()

Dim MergedAreas As Variant
Dim MyPics() As String
Dim PicsLoc As String
Dim Temp1 As String
Dim Temp2 As String
Dim Pic As Picture
Dim Cnt As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

PicsLoc = "A7:A284"  'Change the location of the pictures, accordingly

MergedAreas = Array("C2:C2", "C3:C3", "C4:C4", "C5:C5", "D2:D2", "D3:D3", "D4:D4", "D5:D5", "E2:E2", "E3:E3", "E4:E4", "E5:E5", "F2:F2", "F3:F3", "F4:F4", "F5:F5", "G2:G2", "G3:G3", "G4:G4", "G5:G5")

Cnt = 0
Randomize
For Each Pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
    If Union(Pic.TopLeftCell, Range(PicsLoc)).Address = Range(PicsLoc).Address Then
        ReDim Preserve MyPics(0 To 1, 0 To Cnt)
        MyPics(0, Cnt) = Pic.Name
        MyPics(1, Cnt) = Rnd
        Cnt = Cnt + 1
    End If
Next Pic

If Cnt < 3 Then
    MsgBox "The range " & PicsLoc & " must contain at least 3 pictures...", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Call DeleteRandomPics

For i = 0 To UBound(MyPics, 2) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(MyPics, 2)
        If MyPics(1, i) > MyPics(1, j) Then
            Temp1 = MyPics(0, j)
            Temp2 = MyPics(1, j)
            MyPics(0, j) = MyPics(0, i)
            MyPics(1, j) = MyPics(1, i)
            MyPics(0, i) = Temp1
            MyPics(1, i) = Temp2
        End If
    Next j
Next i

For i = 0 To 19
    ActiveSheet.Pictures(MyPics(0, i)).Copy
    Range(MergedAreas(i)).PasteSpecial
Next i

Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub DeleteRandomPics()

Dim Pic As Picture

For Each Pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
    If Union(Pic.TopLeftCell, Range("A173:O173")).Address = Range("A173:O173").Address Then
        Pic.Delete
    End If
Next Pic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to rewrite the code like this:

```
For i = 0 To 19
    ActiveSheet.Pictures(MyPics(0, i+1)).Copy
    Range(MergedAreas(i)).PasteSpecial
Next i
```

And see whether it works every time?

From the way you assign the `MyPics` Array here:

```
For j = i + 1 To UBound(MyPics, 2)
```

It seems that `j` cannot be `0`.

Comment: I just rewrote with that and it seems to be running! Thanks! Any idea why this error would only pop up some of the time?

Comment: @RileyTaylor - probably it pops up every time when you are trying to refer to an array element that does not exist.